# Extracting Multiple Embedded Files via Oracle Search and Export

Tags: java, oracle

I am currently implementing the Oracle OutsideIn Search and Export tool in Java to extract the metadata and content of different files. I was able to do this on multiple files inside a folder however I wasn't able to extract the files embedded on another file. I would like to know if this is possible in Search and Export.

If not, I'd go for CleanContent but it only accepts Microsoft and PDF files.

Answer (score 1):

Search Export can convert or extract embedded files from within archives or within other types of files.  We distinguish between three different types of embeddings, each of which has its own option to control their conversion.  The three types are archive sub-docs, email attachments, and generic embeddings.  By default the first two are converted, but the third isn't.  To enable generic embeddings conversion, set the SCCEX_XML_EMBEDDINGS flag in the SCCOPT_XML_SEARCHML_FLAGS option.  If you are using the exporter sample app supplied with the SDK, try enabling the following in your CFG file.

embeddingsflag yes

If you are trying to extract a binary copy of the embedding, it becomes a three step process.  On your initial conversion, set the SCCEX_XML_PRODUCEOBJECTINFO flag in the SCCOPT_XML_SEARCHML_FLAGS option.  Use that information for the desired embedding(s) to fill in a SCCDAOBJECT structure that is passed to DAOpenDocument.  The hDoc that is returned from that function can be passed to DASaveInputObject to save a binary copy of the embedding.  This works for any of the three types of embeddings described above.  There is no Java sample app that demonstrates this process.